# Time Series Analysis: Only for Single-Subject Research?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, methodology

Time series analysis (TSA) and interrupted time series analysis (ITSA) research designs are rare in educational research. In extant educational research textbooks I have read, TSA and ITSA are referred to as quasi-experiemntal *single-subject* research designs (Johnson & Chritensen, 2014; Shadish, Cook, & Campbell, 2002; Bryman, 2016). However, it seems that TSA and ITSA have their principle use in econometrics where "single-subject" research is not (I assume) the norm. Why the disconnect?

Moreover, introducing groups would bring along variance. How is this accounted for in a clinical context (like a classroom or school) in describing, explaining, and predicting behavior of groups?

Comment: Here is an interesting approach, that might be useful ?:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2869334/